# Python cmath how to use complex variable in exp's exponent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I know that `cmath` in `Python` is used for complex math.

```
import cmath
cmath.exp(-2j)
```

Now I want to use a variable in its exponent:

```
a = 2
cmath.exp(-a*j)
```

This would raise an error:

```
name 'j' is not defined
```

How to use complex variable in exp's exponent?

Comment: Just write the exponent as  `1j`

Answer (score 5):

When used in literals, `j` is correctly identified as creating a complex object. Beyond there, `j` will just be assumed to be another name and a look-up for its value is going to be triggered.

You still need to define it in the literal:

```
a = 2j
cmath.exp(-a)
(-0.4161468365471424-0.9092974268256817j)
```

Alternatively, feed `a` to `complex`:

```
cmath.exp(-complex(0, a))  # or complex(imag=a)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just write `j` as `1j` so that the parser knows it is a number, and not a 
variable named j,

```
a = 2
cmath.exp(-a*1j)
```

An alternative is to have your variable itself contain a complex number -like
in `a = 2j` and another one is to use the builtin `complex` class name to explictily construct a complex number using "a" as your imaginary part:

```
a = 2
cmath.exp(complex(0, -a))
```

This last form may be more readable by someone not expecting to find complex numbers in your code.